# npm debug module not work on development console

Tags: reactjs, debugging

I was used npm debug, suddenly I have not seen it on the console.
console.log, console.error is fine. only debug is not view.

I don't change source code, env, etc. only macOS auto update

env
react, chrome(safari), macOS(Sierra), webpack

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env.mode),
  'process.env.APP_VERSION': JSON.stringify(config.APP_VERSION),
}),
```

.

```
import Debug from 'debug'; 
const debug = Debug('statSaga');
debug('result : ', 'test');
```

I saw to be like this

[image(debug console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqyPH.png)

But now... clean...

Why I have not seen?? I not edited env, webpack etc.

- console.log, console.error is worked normally.

Comment: "It used to be", "Suddenly I have not seen"...what changed in between?

Comment: 1. I see debug text on chrome development console.

2. suddenly, not see debug text on chrome development console.

I don't change source code, env, etc.
only macOS auto update

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [debug homepage](https://github.com/debug-js/debug#readme) under [browser-support](https://github.com/debug-js/debug#browser-support):

> In Chromium-based web browsers (e.g. Brave, Chrome, and Electron), the JavaScript console will—by default—only show messages logged by debug if the "Verbose" log level is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js does not have console.debug, and since Node.js is executing the JS, when it runs across these it removes them from the compilation. There is no setting anywhere to get it back. Though, perhaps someone might be able to come up with a way to proxy it into being compiled and not parsed out.

Around the web I am seeing/reading that adding { console: true } to the webpack config is having varied results.